# check if the input is a vowel

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am beginning with bash scripting and implementing most of what I have studied in other programming languages to bash. I have to check if the user has entered a vowel character. I came up with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter something: " char
if [[ $char -eq [AEIOUaeiou]* ]]; then
    echo "vowel"
else
    echo "consonant"
fi
```

but when I run it on IdeOne, I get the error:

```
prog.sh: line 3: [[: [AEIOUaeiou]*: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "[AEIOUaeiou]*")
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong here and how to go about correcting it?

I know that the other not-so-clean way is to have multiple conditions `||`ed together. I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: anubhava gave you the right answer. You could also lower case the variable for the comparision: `[[ ${char,,} == *[aeiou]* ]]`

Comment: @glennjackman I was looking it up. What's the `${char,,}` called?

Comment: You'll find it in [the parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) section of the man page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `==` operator for this glob matching:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter something: " char
if [[ "$char" == *[AEIOUaeiou]* ]]; then
    echo "vowel"
else
    echo "consonant"
fi
```

`-eq` - is used for matching numbers

As per `man test`:

```
   INTEGER1 -eq INTEGER2
          INTEGER1 is equal to INTEGER2
```

Comment: The addition of `*` on either sides means any string which has vowels in it? I suck at regex :D

Comment: `-eq` is a numerical operation, it doesn't work on strings (that are not interpretable as numbers).

Comment: I was updating it. `-eq` is for comparing numbers. Yes `*` on either side just checks for presence of vowels anywhere.

Comment: Hi Anubhava, i was trying the above program but modified a little bit, but got stuck. I am trying to check if the entered value is more than one character and if it is not an alphabet. 

`#!/usr/bin/bash 
read -p "Enter something: " char 
if [[ ${#char} != 1 && "$char" != [a-z] ]];then 
echo "Not a valid character" 
else if [[ "$char" == [AEIOUaeiou] ]]; then 
echo "vowel" else echo "consonant" 
fi 
fi`

Comment: I think you should try: `"$char" != *[a-z]*`

Comment: tried but no use... the condition itself not getting executed.. here is the sample o/p
`[root@host-7-113 ~]# sh -x test
+ read -p 'Enter something: ' char
Enter something: 2
+ [[ 1 != 1 ]]
+ [[ 2 == *[AEIOUaeiou]* ]]
+ echo consonant
consonant`

Comment: @monu: Difficult to understand the problem from comments. Suggest you to open a new question and we'll attend.